# Break javascript loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have following code to use google images search API:

```
google.load('search', '1');   
    function searchComplete(searcher) {
      // Check that we got results
      if (searcher.results && searcher.results.length > 0) {
        // Grab our content div, clear it.
        var contentDiv = document.getElementById('contentimg');
        contentDiv.innerHTML = '';

        // Loop through our results, printing them to the page.
        var results = searcher.results;
        for (var i = 1; i < results.length; i++) {
          // For each result write it's title and image to the screen
          var result = results[i];
          var imgContainer = document.createElement('div');



          var newImg = document.createElement('img');
          // There is also a result.url property which has the escaped version
          newImg.src = result.tbUrl;


          imgContainer.appendChild(newImg);

          // Put our title + image in the content
          contentDiv.appendChild(imgContainer);
```

The problem is, it gives me 3 image results. How to break a loop and show only the 1st one instead of 3 images?
if I change `for (var i = 1; i < results.length; i++)` to `for (var i = 3; i < results.length; i++)` it shows only one image, but image shown is the 3rd one and I need to show 1st one :)
Please advice

Comment: If you're certain that you only need the first image, then why not drop the loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use a for loop at all.  Just replace all instances of `i` with 0.

```
google.load('search', '1');   
    function searchComplete(searcher) {
      // Check that we got results
      if (searcher.results && searcher.results.length > 0) {
        // Grab our content div, clear it.
        var contentDiv = document.getElementById('contentimg');
        contentDiv.innerHTML = '';

        var result = searcher.results[0];

        var imgContainer = document.createElement('div');

        var newImg = document.createElement('img');
        // There is also a result.url property which has the escaped version
        newImg.src = result.tbUrl;

        imgContainer.appendChild(newImg);

        // Put our title + image in the content
        contentDiv.appendChild(imgContainer);
```

0 means the first item returned (almost all number sequences in programming start at 0!) so all other results will be ignored.

Comment: Answer adjusted to clarify this :)

Comment: Seems like good idea, but after adding your code It shows no image at all.. :(

Comment: I will adjust my answer to give the full code listing, you might be leaving in lines you don't need.

Comment: fantastic, thanks a lot. I didnt noticed it was } (to end the loop) at the end of my code. I've deleted it and all works. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

use `break statement`. It will terminate the loop once the image is found and hence you will have only the first one.

```
      for (var i = 1; i < results.length; i++) {
      // For each result write it's title and image to the screen
      var result = results[i];
      var imgContainer = document.createElement('div');



      var newImg = document.createElement('img');
      // There is also a result.url property which has the escaped version
      newImg.src = result.tbUrl;


      imgContainer.appendChild(newImg);

      // Put our title + image in the content
      contentDiv.appendChild(imgContainer);
       //Berore the end of the loop
      if(i==1)
      {
      break;
      }
   }
```

Comment: This could work but is a bit weird. If you don't need to loop then why loop?

Comment: @pimvdb: true, its just to help even if more than one images are needed as it will work in all the situations by just modifying the no of images needed.

Comment: One could also change `i < results.length` to `i < 4` to show 3 images. `break` is a bit odd here, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

When you only want one element, you don't need a for loop. You can access the first element of an array with

```
result = results[0];
```

Arrays are zero-based. So when it contains three images, the images are named results[0], results[1] and results[2].